# How to center articles in a section

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, position

Having trouble figuring this out if anyone can help me id really appreciate it! :)

Basically im building, or well trying to build a responsive wesbite using HTML5, i have it all structured how I want and everything but one thing is wrong and i cant figure out how to correct it.

I have set a max-width for all my sections of 1000px and all the sections have been centred normally using margin: 0 auto; but all the articles inside the section are still left aligned?

I tried setting a global rule for article tags using

`article {
     margin: 0 auto;
}`

but this didnt work so does anyone know whats going on? Here is a link to a fiddle showing what i mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/DannyW86/9YYNR/1/

here is a screen grab of how it appears in the browser, you can clearly see that the 3 articles with the icons are not centred beneath the text above

[image]

Comment: If you want to align the text to the center and not to the left. You use the article p { text-align: center; }

Comment: They are centered. You just need to increase the size of your window.. see http://jsfiddle.net/DannyW86/9YYNR/1/embedded/result/

Comment: that's not displaying as centred on my laptop?

Comment: @DannyW86 They are centered within 1000px. If your screen size isn't 1000px, then they aren't going to be centered. Look at the full screen result.

Comment: My screen is a lot more then 1000px, if you use chrome developer tools to look at the section you will see the section is centred in the page correct, but the 3 articles in the section are left aligned inside the section

Comment: @DannyW86 apply not just margin-right to article element, but use margins on the left and right side, then you will see that they are centred.

Comment: I don't follow you? I just added margin: 0 auto; which should cover both left and right? Please see the image i have just attached to my original post to see what i mean.

Comment: But the section is 1000px wide. The (floating left) articles in it are 250px wide. Why do you expect the articles to be in the center of the section? Make the section 750px wide or give the articles `margin:0 41px`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't center elements with `margin: auto;` if they are placed next to each other.

Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/leo/LzKTy/

(!!): Note the `display: table;`-attribute which i have addet to **#boxcontent** and the `display: table-cell;`-attribute i've addet to **article**.